# How to send images using "flutter_open_whatsapp" package?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am building an app that has to be able to send text and images directly to a specific WhatsApp number using this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_open_whatsapp. But the plugin has not implemented for the multimedia data.  What exactly am I supposed to do?

Comment: That package ``doesn't support sending multimedia files``. You can check here https://github.com/rohit1814/flutter_open_whatsapp/issues/1

Comment: are there any solution except using that package or maybe sending images via whatsapp API ?

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/MertcanDinler/Flutter-Advanced-Share

Comment: i've tried it before, but i want to send the images directly to unsaved number? what must i do?